# How to create complex hierarchies of lists in R

Tags: r, list, dataframe, vector, lapply

I have received help on how to create a set of lists within lists, however I have been unable to add another layer / extend the depth of my lists. All I want is to add a final 'layer' in each list, that reads, 'DataFrame', 'DataFrame2', and so on. Currently I have:

```
Layer1 = c('AA', 'BB', 'CC', 'DD')

myList=setNames(as.list(Layer1),Layer1)

myList=lapply(myList, function(x){
  setNames(vector("list",length(Layer1)),paste0(x," vs ",Layer1))
})
```

Which produces `myList`, containing `AA`, `BB`, `CC` and `DD`, in each of those lists is a further list e.g. `AA vs BB`, `AA vs BB` etc, or in the case of `BB` the lists inside will read `BB vs AA`, `BB vs BB` (referred to hereafter as `?? vs ??` files) and so on and so forth.

So I thought I could easily add an additional layer to this by doing something along the lines of...

```
Layer1 = c('AA', 'BB', 'CC', 'DD')
Layer3 = c('DataFrame', 'DataFrame2', 'Matrix', 'Matrix2')

myList=setNames(as.list(Layer1),Layer1)

myList=lapply(myList, function(x){
  setNames(vector("list",length(Layer1)),paste0(x," vs ",Layer1))

  myList[i]=lapply(myList, function(x){
  setNames(vector("list",length(Layer3)),Layer3)

  })  
})
```

Where I've naively tried to use `myList[i]` (which I know won't work, but I'm not sure if anything I'm doing will) to indicate that I'd like to move down a tier and start adding blank `DataFrame` and `Matrix` vectors (into my `?? vs ??` sublists) so that I have 'empty slots'- so to speak - to move my data into in the future.

Ultimately I would like each `?? vs ??` folder to contain a blank `DataFrame`, `DataFrame2`, `Matrix`, `Matrix2`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`lapply` loops over each element of a list like structure and applies a function to it. Notably, it does *not* include a positional argument.

What you want to do is:

- run through all elements of `Layer1` and create for each element a list, which in turn
- contains `Layer1` many elements wach of these elements contain
- as many elements as given in `Layer3`

**Code**

```
Layer1 <- c('AA', 'BB', 'CC', 'DD')
Layer3 <- c('DataFrame', 'DataFrame2', 'Matrix', 'Matrix2')

my_list <- lapply(Layer1, function(el_layer1_outer) {
   ## create a list with |Layer1| elements
   ## this we do by creating first an inner list vector(.)
   ## and the repeating it |Layer1| times
   ret <- rep(list(setNames(vector("list", length(Layer3)), 
                            Layer3)), 
              length(Layer1))
   setNames(ret, ## ret has no proper names yet
            paste(el_layer1_outer, "vs.", Layer1)) 
})
names(my_list) <- Layer1 ## could have been done with setNames as well
str(my_list)
```

> ```
> List of 4
>  $ AA:List of 4
>   ..$ AA vs. AA:List of 4
>   .. ..$ DataFrame : NULL
>   .. ..$ DataFrame2: NULL
>   .. ..$ Matrix    : NULL
>   .. ..$ Matrix2   : NULL
>   ..$ AA vs. BB:List of 4
>   .. ..$ DataFrame : NULL
>   .. ..$ DataFrame2: NULL
>   .. ..$ Matrix    : NULL
>   .. ..$ Matrix2   : NULL
>   ..$ AA vs. CC:List of 4
>   .. ..$ DataFrame : NULL
>   .. ..$ DataFrame2: NULL
>   .. ..$ Matrix    : NULL
>   .. ..$ Matrix2   : NULL
>   ..$ AA vs. DD:List of 4
>   .. ..$ DataFrame : NULL
>   .. ..$ DataFrame2: NULL
>   .. ..$ Matrix    : NULL
>   .. ..$ Matrix2   : NULL
>  $ BB:List of 4
>   ..$ BB vs. AA:List of 4
>   .. ..$ DataFrame : NULL
>   .. ..$ DataFrame2: NULL
>   .. ..$ Matrix    : NULL
>   .. ..$ Matrix2   : NULL
>   ..$ BB vs. BB:List of 4
>   .. ..$ DataFrame : NULL
>   .. ..$ DataFrame2: NULL
>   .. ..$ Matrix    : NULL
>   .. ..$ Matrix2   : NULL
>   ..$ BB vs. CC:List of 4
>   .. ..$ DataFrame : NULL
>   .. ..$ DataFrame2: NULL
>   .. ..$ Matrix    : NULL
>   .. ..$ Matrix2   : NULL
>   ..$ BB vs. DD:List of 4
>   .. ..$ DataFrame : NULL
>   .. ..$ DataFrame2: NULL
>   .. ..$ Matrix    : NULL
>   .. ..$ Matrix2   : NULL
>  $ CC:List of 4
>   ..$ CC vs. AA:List of 4
>   .. ..$ DataFrame : NULL
>   .. ..$ DataFrame2: NULL
>   .. ..$ Matrix    : NULL
>   .. ..$ Matrix2   : NULL
>   ..$ CC vs. BB:List of 4
>   .. ..$ DataFrame : NULL
>   .. ..$ DataFrame2: NULL
>   .. ..$ Matrix    : NULL
>   .. ..$ Matrix2   : NULL
>   ..$ CC vs. CC:List of 4
>   .. ..$ DataFrame : NULL
>   .. ..$ DataFrame2: NULL
>   .. ..$ Matrix    : NULL
>   .. ..$ Matrix2   : NULL
>   ..$ CC vs. DD:List of 4
>   .. ..$ DataFrame : NULL
>   .. ..$ DataFrame2: NULL
>   .. ..$ Matrix    : NULL
>   .. ..$ Matrix2   : NULL
>  $ DD:List of 4
>   ..$ DD vs. AA:List of 4
>   .. ..$ DataFrame : NULL
>   .. ..$ DataFrame2: NULL
>   .. ..$ Matrix    : NULL
>   .. ..$ Matrix2   : NULL
>   ..$ DD vs. BB:List of 4
>   .. ..$ DataFrame : NULL
>   .. ..$ DataFrame2: NULL
>   .. ..$ Matrix    : NULL
>   .. ..$ Matrix2   : NULL
>   ..$ DD vs. CC:List of 4
>   .. ..$ DataFrame : NULL
>   .. ..$ DataFrame2: NULL
>   .. ..$ Matrix    : NULL
>   .. ..$ Matrix2   : NULL
>   ..$ DD vs. DD:List of 4
>   .. ..$ DataFrame : NULL
>   .. ..$ DataFrame2: NULL
>   .. ..$ Matrix    : NULL
>   .. ..$ Matrix2   : NULL
> ```

Comment: Thank you, that's really helpful and the inclusion of explanatory comments goes a long way.